# how to replicate weblogic admin console parameters to multiple site

Tags: automation, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have weblogic 12c clusters setup in 10 different destination. They are of the same setup and it act as a failover in same cases

I will like to make a tuning config change on the admin console such as change of datasource connection pool or change of thread pool size for performance.

Is there a way that I can automate 1 config change and applies to all different destination cluster admin console rather than manually access each admin console to make the config change.

Much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: the best way is to create a wlst script that will update your domain configuration (thread tuning, datasource, etc...) and to run it against all your domains. You can start with the recording mode in the admin console to create the script.

Comment: hi Emmanuel. thanks for the suggestion, will look into it for the option. I was thinking after the script is setup, can i use automation tools such as ansible to push it to all relevant domains?

Comment: sure you can. You can also do all your modifications from a single point. Your wlst script can connect to each admin server an apply required updates in the domain.